# I need some sculpting advice and best practices

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I’ve been sculpting on and off for about a year now, mostly just doing fantasy stuff like dragons and monsters. Things that don’t need super correct anatomy or stuff like that to look cool. I started like that so I can get comfortable with the tools and understand sculpting as a whole.

But now I want to get serious and learn how to sculpt characters, human characters. I started out with the body as it seemed easier, and while it probably has anatomical mistakes, I ended with pleasing results. However, the face is a different beast entirelly.

I’ve sculpted maybe 30 faces now? And only now I got a good result. Something that doesn’t look like a Skinwalker at the least.

[image]

This is the best I’ve managed to do without using any references at all. And here is my problem. I only have one monitor to work on, and it’s not a big one either. So how can I place dozens of references and still be able to sculpt all on one monitor?

As of right now, I feel lost on a human face. This character was suppose to be a male, but ended up looking like a female. And I feel is because I don’t have references to guide me. And speaking of references, does anyone know any good references specially designed to teach someone how to sculpt a human face?

And finally, what are the best practices to learn how to sculpt human characters as fast as possible?

And, I would like to end this by saying that I’m not interested on becoming a character artist, or an artist at all. I’m a solo game dev and I wanted to make my own assets for my game instead of buying them. Which is why I’m in Blender and am learning Sculpting, Texturing and animation. I’m also not necessarily aiming at realism since I want to have a more stylized aproach to my game.

So, to sum it all up:

-How can I place and use references while still being able to sculpt all in one single monitor?

-What are the best references for beginners to use to quickly learn how to sculpt human faces and where to find them?

-What are the best practices to become good at sculpting in the shortest ammount of time?

Comment: I think only your first question is suitable for this site format. Also only one question per post is preferred. What's wrong in using the image editor or placing reference images directly in the 3D space?  Most know resources for Blender are listed here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender. Best practice, best tutorials,... it's an high debatable topic that fits better in Blender Artist. Have you check there?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and make a single clear question that is not opinion based. Make new questions in different posts, one question per page. Please take a minute to take the [tour] to understand how to make better use of this site. Read also the following [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)